# Limit the rows returned in Include entity

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have simple data model Project,Member and ProjectMember where Project to Member has many-to-many relationship. Therefore ProjectMember table contains the both foreign keys.

I writes the code

```
var result= db.Projects.Include(p=>p.ProjectMembers).Where(p=>p.ProjectMembers.Any(pm=>pm.DeletedUser==1));
```

and I see `result.ProjectMembers` count is 2 . Here I have got additional record with DeletedUser is not equal to 1

Did I do something wrong here?

What is the expression I have to use to get the only one record (or many with DeletedUser=1) for `result.ProjectMembers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for `Project`s having *at least one* (= any) `ProjectMember` with `DeletedUser == 1`. This condition is met. Other `ProjectMember`s of the `Project` can have any other value than 1 for `DeletedUser`.

If you want the `Project` with *only* `ProjectMember`s with `DeletedUser == 1` you should start the query at `ProjectMember`:

```
ProjectMembers.Include("Project").Where(pm => pm.DeletedUser == 1)
```